# Which Array Method to use (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, methods

I have an array,

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

let us say I give it a condition to return numbers above 3, using the .filter() method, returns a new array.

But I need it to return the original array but making the array values that do not meet the conditions empty.

*The new array should be*

```
[ , , , , 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Is this possible?

#### Edit

Here are the changed requirements.

I have an array,

```
const arr = [
  { myNumber: 1, name: 'one' },
  { myNumber: 3, name: 'tree' },
  { myNumber: 6, name: 'six' },
  { myNumber: 8, name: 'eight' }
];
```

let us say I give it a condition to return names that include alphabet **I**, using the .filter() method, returns a new array.
But I need it to return the original array but making the array values that do not meet the conditions empty

*The new array should be*

```
const arr = [
  { myNumber: '', name: '' },
  { myNumber: '', name: '' },
  { myNumber: 6, name: 'six' },
  { myNumber: 8, name: 'eight' }
];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, use `.map` instead of filter, and return the element/null instead of a bool.

Comment: [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is probably what you need

Comment: To be clear, `arr.map(i => i > 3 ? i : undefined)`

Comment: what do you mean with *empty* a sparse array or `undefined` as value?

Comment: at everyone who wants to propose [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ... *"The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."* ... the OP explicitly does ask for ... *"But i need it to return the original array."*

Comment: Since the OP was asking for an ***array method*** I, as so often, want to promote [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It proves itself to be an elegant swiss-knife again and again, ... [but see yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240389/which-array-method-to-use-js/64240882#64240882) ...

Comment: @RaphaelInyang ... every approach that actively `delete`s an item from the original array also meets the expected result of `[ , , , , 4, 5, 6 ]` (the stackoverflow console.log just does not show it that way. But one can try the examples in e.g. a browser console). All other approaches do not (re)produce the before mentioned sparse array but rely on replacing the item explicitly with a `null` or `undefined` value; thus the mutated array is not a sparse one.

Comment: ive updated the question to include real information

Comment: @RaphaelInyang ... firstly it is considered to be *bad style* to change fundamental requirements after receiving a lot of answers because most of the A's focus on a straightforward solution and do not take generic approaches into account. Secondly, adapting the changed *condition* into any of the provided solutions by yourself is not such a difficult task. At third, from what I can see now, from the just changed requirements ... you changed the game entirely ... you might prepare yourself for downvotes.

Comment: I didn't know, I just wanted to know if it worked for numbers, then I saw it did, I thought it would be better to just edit it to the real thing instead of asking a new question

Comment: when I tried to use it for the objects, it didn't work as expected, it returned an empty array

Comment: a new array with same name as const does not work. please stay at the old question, accept any of the answers or not and ask a new question. **BUT** don't change the question to a different question with part of same questions arise as for the first question, like new array vs mutating exsting array or deleting vs changing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new answer is going to prove that even with entirely changed requirements a generic idea (a generic base approach) can be adapted easily to the changes but still can be recognized.

With the new requirements one does not need to change the original array itself but each item (reference) of it. Thus [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will be the new array method of choice.

The [`reduce` and `condition` based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240389/which-array-method-to-use-js/64240882#64240882) of the former requirements provides the main idea of working with customizable functions for e.g `condition` and, newly introduced with this approach, the item specific mutation via `resetValues`  ...

```js
function resetConditionMatchingItemValuesViaBoundConfig(item) {
  const { condition, resetValues } = this; // `this` equals bound `config`.
  if (condition(item)) {
    // mutate an original array's item.
    resetValues(item);
  }
}

function isItemNumberValueLowerEqualThanThree(item) {
  return (item.myNumber <= 3);
}
function resetItemValues(item) {
  item.myNumber = Number.NaN;
//item.myNumber = '';
  item.name = '';
}

const arr = [
  { myNumber: 1, name: 'one' },
  { myNumber: 3, name: 'tree' },
  { myNumber: 6, name: 'six' },
  { myNumber: 8, name: 'eight' }
];
console.log('before mutation ... arr :', arr);

arr.forEach(resetConditionMatchingItemValuesViaBoundConfig, {
  condition: isItemNumberValueLowerEqualThanThree,
  resetValues: resetItemValues,
});
console.log('after mutation ... arr :', arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what if i want to add a specific styling to the elements in the array? @peterSelinger

Comment: @RaphaelInyang ... what do you mean by... / what do you expect from a...  *"specific styling"*?

Comment: i want the array items that do not the standard to have a styling lets say bold while the others that meet the standard italic

Comment: lets say i want to use this in a list

Comment: @RaphaelInyang ... 1/2 Why do you keep changing requirements? Shape for yourself a clear understanding about what you really want to achieve. Break it down into short English instructions. This is already close to an approach that can be implemented as code. From your last two thrown sentences above, I'm barely able to guess what you really want, and whether the last suggested approach of mine would be even remain a valid/stable enough base.

Comment: @RaphaelInyang ... 2/2 And of cause we are already far away from the original Q. that was asking *"Which Array Method to use"*. Please try to solve the new problem yourself. In case you fail, come back to SO and ask for support where you've got stuck.

Answer (score 4):

To map value and modify existing array use `forEach` method and modify element of array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
arr.forEach((ele, idx) => {
  if(ele <= 3) arr[idx] = null;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: quoting the OP ... *"But i need it to return the original array"*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger updated answer to modify original array

Answer (score 3):

You could delete unwanted items.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] <= 3) delete array[i];

console.log(array);
array.forEach((v, i) => console.log(v, i));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: so what does this log to the console?

Answer (score 2):

`[ , , , , 4, 5, 6 ]` is not possible. However, `[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 4, 5, 6 ]` is possible, as well as `[ null, null, null, null, 4, 5, 6 ]`.

So, instead of using `.filter()`, I would use `map()` :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const newArr = arr.map((x) => x <= 3 ? undefined : x);

console.log(newArr);
```

If you want the changes to be made in place, use the same logic, but in a regular loop :

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
arr.forEach((element, index, original) => {
  if (element <= 3)
    original[index] = undefined;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: quoting the OP ... *"But i need it to return the original array"*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger ah, yep, good catch. Didn't notice the changes should be made in place

Comment: @Cid you need to edit your description as well, because it mentions map.

Comment: @SecondSon feel free to edit my answer if you think it can be improved

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP was asking for an ***array method*** I, as so often, want to promote [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It proves itself to be an elegant swiss-knife again and again, ... but see yourself ...

```js
function deleteConditionMatchingItem(condition, item, idx, arr) {
  if (condition(item)) {
    // mutate the original array.
    delete arr[idx];
  }
  return condition;
}
function isLowerEqualThanThree(value) {
  return (value <= 3);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
console.log('before mutation ... arr :', arr);

arr.reduce(deleteConditionMatchingItem, isLowerEqualThanThree);
console.log('after mutation ... arr :', arr);

console.log('("0" in arr ) ? ', ("0" in arr ));
console.log('("1" in arr ) ? ', ("1" in arr ));
console.log('("2" in arr ) ? ', ("2" in arr ));
console.log('("3" in arr ) ? ', ("3" in arr ));
console.log('("4" in arr ) ? ', ("4" in arr ));
console.log('("5" in arr ) ? ', ("5" in arr ));
console.log('("6" in arr ) ? ', ("6" in arr ));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```